# How can i program only getter property?

Tags: c#, winforms, visual-studio

I was trying to program only getter in C# and it showed me this error:

> "Error 7 'NET.BusinessTier.SalesQuote.AmountDue.get' must declare a body because it is not marked abstract or ex-tern. Automatically implemented properties must define both get and set accessors."

I programmed and do not need any setter. How can I resolve it? [link to my assignment](http://aceteam.ca/adev2005-15/Assignments/Assignment_1/01kdtrgk.pdf)

```
public decimal Salestax { get; }
```

Comment: Is that dash syntax valid?

Comment: ohh its "public decimal Salestax {get;}"

Comment: What do you expect that to do?  You need to make the getter do something.

Comment: I just need getter property only for now

Comment: Visual Studio 2010 Pro Visual Basic C# Windows Form Application

Comment: How do you expect to initialize the value of the property?

Comment: just as an decimal saletax

Comment: That would always be zero. Don't you want to be able to set its value when you create an instance of your class?

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/101325/discussion-between-user3443401-and-yacoub-massad).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Typically you would not want to have a property as get only because, you have no way to update it from the initial value. You might want to make the property so that it cannot be set from outside the class, which is most likly what you are looking for in this case.

For this your property would look like this:

```
public double SalesTax { get; private set; }
```

This allows you to change the value of SalesTax from within this class. Other areas of your program can read this property but, they can never change the value.

Comment: OP admitted that the `-` was a typo. And it is _not allowed_ to declare a getter-only _auto_-property. In C#6 you can do it with the initializer.

Comment: Your first statement isn't quite correct.  There is s small subset of non-alpha-numeric characters that are allowed in identifier names.  _ and @ jump to mind.  Not sure when these might have been added or if they have been there all along.

Answer (score 1):

In C#6 you can do this:

```
public decimal Salestax { get; } = 42;
// or
public decimal Salestax_v2 => 43;
```

The first version is a getter-only property that is initialized to `42`. The second version is an expression-bodied member. The expression (`43` in this case) is executed by every access to `Salestax_v2`

Before C#6 it is simply not possible, but you may try a `private` setter:

```
public decimal Salestax { get; private set; }
```

and set the value in your constructor.

Answer (score 0):

```
public decimal Salestax { get; }
```

The compiler is able to tell that, the compiler notices that this property will never have something different than "0" and raises this error because it knows this line of code doesn't make sense.

If you want you only want this variable to return a constant value, you can go on with René Vogt's answer and just assign this value.

If you just didn't **implement** this variable yet, I think it's a good practice to explicitly say so:

```
public decimal Salestax { get { throw new NotImplementedException(); } }
```